# produce same result in in foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter

Hi I'm trying to get the num rows of every data that equal on the value produce by foreach loop here's my samp code

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM tblsamp");
  foreach ($query->result() as $row){

      $subquery = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM other_table WHERE foo like  '%$row->some_col%'");

        echo $subquery->num_rows();
        // Ill get the num rows here equal on the value of $row->som_col
}
```

Here's the sample output so you can visualize the data"

```
name    |     NoRows
name1   |       6
name2   |       6
name3   |       6
name4   |       6
```

the problem is if name1 detect '6' rows the name2,name3,name4. and so on will also output '6' rows which is that the number of rows on each name is different.

Why im getting the same result of name1?

Hoping for your answer guys! thanks!

Comment: You should do a `JOIN` with a `GROUP BY` to get all results in one query to the database.

Comment: is there any possible way without doing join?

Comment: yeah, what you are doing is the other possible way but why execute potentially hundreds of queries and write a lot of code when one query and a few lines does the job better?

Comment: maybe as a beginner you wont use join because you are not familiar to it but its better to explore things that you don't know yet

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use group and count request ?

```
select t.name, count(*) 
from tblsamp t 
left join other_table on foo like concat('%',t.some_col,'%')
group by t.name
```